# Can you reorder tiddlers in a page?

Tags: tiddlywiki

Is there any way to reorder the displayed tiddlers on a page? Googles has utterly failed to help me: all I can find are full drag-and-drop implementations that are *far* too elaborate when all I want is the possibility of reordering the tidlers that are showing on the page.

Normally links from a tiddler open under that tiddler, other links open at the top. What if I want to, say, switch around two of the currently displayed tiddler? Has anyone actually built such an extension? The one exemple that comes to mind is the Tumblr queue, which is pretty much exactly what I'd like to be able to do.

Answer (score 1):

[This resource](http://www.tiddlytools.com/#NavigationPackage)  is delightful and easy to install.

It's easy to drag-and drop, and if I have many tiddlers open then I press the "Focus" button on the nearest tiddler to fold all the others.

An underscore in the title will make the tiddler non-movable.  I started using a hyphen instead.